# Как сделать так, что бы событие click по переднему элементу, не затрагивало элемент под ним?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не думаю что в описании я правильно объяснил. Но суть такая, есть Блок в котором есть БлокХовер (он имеет стиль top:100%, так что он уезжает вниз за пределы родителя) и при нажатии на Блок, БлокХовер выезжает (приобретает top:0px). Вот тут проблема, нужно что бы при нажатии на БлокХовер он уезжал обратно (принимал top:100%). Но как я понял одновременно с этим обрабатывается событие клика Блока

[Это пример на codepen](https://codepen.io/dontraffic/pen/qBaKmqN)

```
<div class="block">
 <div class="blockHover"></div>
</div>

.block{
 width: 300px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: green;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.blockHover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  transition: .4s ease;
 }

 $('.block').click(function() {
  $('.blockHover').css('top', '0');
 });

 $('.blockHover').click(function() {
  $('.blockHover').css('top', '100%');
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вызовите

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

внутри события

```js
$('.block').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); 
  $('.blockHover').css('top', '0');
});

$('.blockHover').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); 
  $('.blockHover').css('top', '100%');
});
```

```css
.block{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blockHover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  transition: .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
   <div class="blockHover"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте
event.stopPropagation();
Что бы запретить событие всплывать.

```
$('.block').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('.blockHover').css('top', '0');
});

$('.blockHover').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('.blockHover').css('top', '100%');  
});
```

Comment: Чем этот ответ лучше соседнего?

Comment: да ничем особо. в момент когда отвечал, еще не было ответов. Вы посмотрите на время почти в одно и то же время публиковалось.

Comment: Ага, вижу, 2 минуты.